# MalformedCSVError with rails CSV (FasterCSV)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, csv, fastercsv

I'm having serious issues trying to parse some CSV in rails right now.
Basically my app gets a user to upload a CSV file. The app then converts the file to ensure it is in UTF-8 format, then attempts to parse it and process it. Whenever the app attempts to parse it however, I get the MalformedCSVError stating "Illegal quoting on line 1"

Now what I don't get, is if I copy the original file into a new document and save it, then I can parse it on a rails console without a problem.

If I attempt to parse the original file, it complains about an invalid character for UTF-8 encoding (the file isn't in UTF-8 hence the app converts it)

If I attempt to parse the file which the app has converted to UTF-8 and changed the line endings to LF, it fails to parse.

If I do a file diff between the version the app has produced, and the copy/paste version that I have made (which works) there are 0 differences so I really can't figure out why one is parsable, and one is not.

Any suggestions? My app is processing the file as follows :

```
def create
@survey = Survey.new(params[:survey])

# Now we need to try and convert this to UTF-8 if it isn't already
 encoded = File.read(@survey.survey_data.current_path)
encoding = CharlockHolmes::EncodingDetector.detect(encoded)

# We've got a guess at the encoding, 
# so we can try and convert it but it 
# may still fail so we need to handle 
# that
begin
  re_encoded = CharlockHolmes::Converter.convert(encoded, encoding[:encoding], 'UTF-8')
  re_encoded = re_encoded.gsub(/\r\n?/, "\n")

  # Now replace the uploaded file
  File.open(@survey.survey_data.current_path, 'w') { |f|
    f.write(re_encoded)
  }
rescue ArgumentError
  puts "UH OH!!!!!"
end

puts "#{@survey.survey_data.current_path}"
@parsed = CSV.read(@survey.survey_data.current_path)
```

end

The file uploading gem is CarrierWave if that makes any difference.

Please can someone help me as this is driving me insane!

**Edit**

The error says it's on line 1. Line 1 (assuming it doesn't index from 0) is

```
"Survey","RD","GarrysMDs","NigelsMDs","PaulsMDs","StephensMDs","BrinleyJ","CarolineP","DaveL","GrantR","GregS","Kent","NeilC","NicolaP","AndyC","DarrenS","DeanB","KarenF","PaulR","RichardF","SteveG","BrianG","GordonA","NickD","NickR","NickT","RayL","SimonH","EdmondH","JasonF","MikeS","SamanthaN","TimB","TravisF","AlanS","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q5","Q6","Q7","Q8PM","Q8N","Q9","Q10","Q11","Q12","Q13","Q14","Q15","Q16PM","Q16N","Q17PM","Q17N","Q18PM","Q18N","Q19","Q20","Q21","Q22","comment","Q23.1","Q23.2","Q23.3","TQ23.1","TQ23.2","VPM","VN","VQ1","VQ2","VQ3","VQ4","VQ5","VQ6","VQ7","VQ8N","VQ8PM","VQ9","VQ10","VQ11","VQ12","VQ13","VQ14","VQ15","VQ16","VQ16N","VQ16PM","VQ17","VQ17N","VQ17PM","VQ18","VQ18N","VQ18PM","VQ19","VQ20","VQ21","VQ22","VQ23.1","VQ23.2","VQ23.3","VRD","XQ16","XQ17","XQ18"
```

Comment: What line is the error for?

Comment: it says line 1. I'll add that to the question now

Comment: How do you do a diff? If one fails to parse and the other does not then there has to be a difference between the two. Don't just run `diff` on it, but run `cmp`. It will catch exact byte differences.

Comment: Running `cmp` on the 2 files gives me `differ: char 1, line 1` which is a quote mark?

Comment: Are the file sizes exactly the same for both?

Comment: running `du` on both of the files gives me 11584 for both of them. Finder says they're both 5.9mb as well so they're the same

Comment: You can use `hexdump` or `hd` to look at the bytes of the files. My initial guess is the converter has converted the quotes to those bent inside-outside quotes for some reason. Wondering if you add `:encoding => 'U'` to the `CSV.read` options does it help?

Comment: adding the :encoding => 'U' gives me `warning: Unsupported encoding U ignored` and then the same error as before :(

Comment: Why do you need to convert to UTF8 anyway? In any case it seems the error is in the conversion of the quote characters. You have to investigate it yourself since we don't have access to the file.

Comment: It fails to parse in the format it's uploaded in. Converting to UTF-8 seemed like a nice way of allowing any encoding to be uploaded and still be able to handle it. I'll do a hex dump and see if I can figure out what's wrong

Comment: Just ran `cmp` again with the -b flag, and got a slightly different output. `differ: byte 1, line 1 is 357 ?  42 "` Not really sure what to make of that but obviously something is different. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well that was irritating!

Turns out the file had a BOM which was causing the CSV parser to break. Loading the file with

```
CSV.open("path/to/file.csv", "rb:bom|encoding")
```

allowed it to parse it perfectly! So annoyed how long it took to track down but it's now working and with no need to convert to UTF-8 now either!

Comment: Oh dear :) Good that you figured it out. For those wondering: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark . You know you can accept your own answers...